Average Energy and Magnetization of One Site Hubbard Model
I have been trying to implement the exercises from Section 2 part B (for which $t = 0$, and only considering the effects of U) given in this set of lecture notes - Numerical Studies of Disordered Tight-Binding Hamiltonians by R.T. Scalettar (link). I was able to reproduce the graph of Figure 7. I calculated the expectation value of the energy from the partition function using this formula $$(-1/(\beta \times Z))\times \delta Z/ \delta \beta$$. After solving this, I am getting this expression as shown in the image below . However, in the lecture note, they are only getting the second term with U only. I do not understand why they are neglecting the term with mu. My guess is that since mu controls the filling of the electrons, and the formula that I used above holds only when the number of particles is fixed, so I assumed mu would be a constant, and therefore they are neglecting it. But, the second term involves a mu in its exponent, so I am guessing this reasoning is incorrect. It'd be of great help if someone can explain this part.
In addition to this, I am also calculating the magnetization which is the average of square of (n[j, down] - n[j, up]) (eq1). Since I have the expression for the average occupation number (R) which is (n[j, down] + n[j, up]). After expanding the square in eq1, I was able to obtain an expression for magnetization which is $$(2 \times R - (R^2))$$. It'd be of great if this can also be confirmed, since I am not getting the correct plot as given in figure 8 of the same paper.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
